# Endereços de memória

Tags: memória, arquitetura-computadores

Minha arquitetura é de 32 bits então meus endereços de memoria são de 32 bits? pois estava usando um *debug* vendo uns códigos *assembly* e chegou em uma parte onde tinha um *loop* , e ele ia pegando byte por byte de uma *string* e cada caractere da *string* tinha um endereço para ela exemplo:

```
0x78650 -> A
0x78651 -> B
```

Como assim os tamanho do meu endereço então é 1 byte ou 4 bytes?

Comment: resposta resolveu seu problema? Ache que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour].

Answer (score 8):

São dois conceitos completamente diferentes. O endereço é 4 bytes (em arquitetura 32 bits). O tamanho do dado pode variar de acordo com seu tipo. Em geral 1 é usado para representar um caractere, mas isto também pode variar. Um caractere é algo abstrato e pode ser definido com vários tamanhos e formas de compor.

Fazendo uma analogia, endereço é a localização de onde fica a casa, o dado é a casa. Sempre tem o mesmo padrão em uma cidade para dizer qual é o endereço, mas as casas tem vários tamanhos e formatos.